# WPF/XAML: Binding to Dictionary<object, object> entry by key

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

I am programming a MVVM-application and in the ViewModel I created a property of the type `Dictionary<Geschäftsjahr, object>`.

The `Geschäftsjahr`-object has 2 properties and holds two different years (f.e.: 2017/18). The ToString()-Method returns the data in exactly this format.

Now I want to bind a certain entry of the dictionary with XAML to a TextBox. 
Is it possible, to access the dictionary in the following way:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=ViewModelProperty[2017/18]} ... />
```

It's very important to access the dictionary over the key. Actually it doesn't work this way...

Thanks, Nicolas

Comment: Looks a little bit complicate to me, why don't you just use another String property where the get is your dictionary with the key you want?

Comment: do you really want to hardcode that textbox to a specific key?

Comment: Yes, I want to bind the TextBox to a specific key, because the TextBox is generated automatically with a certain binding. And I right now, I use the dictionary this way. Changing it to a `Dictionary<string, object>` would be a lot of additional effort. Is the any posibility to bind it like described?

Comment: What about switching your dictionary to a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<Geschäftsjahr, object>>`?

Comment: Would be a possibility, but the `Geschäftsjahr`-object is already a key and the model works with it. So, when I do it this way, I have two key. So you don't see any other way?

Comment: A different idea would be to use a different constructor when initializing the dictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__

In there you could specify that the comparison uses the property that holds the `2017/18` string. Currently your Dictionary is using the default comparer/operator which just compares two objects with eachother.

Comment: Do I understand you right? In the constructor I pass a comparison-function, that compares the string from the Binding-accessor with the `Geschäftsjahr`-object?

Comment: ah, sorry. Brainfart. Disregard my comment. That would only work if you wanted to compare two `Geschäftsjahr` objects.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible, to access the dictionary in the following way ...?

Only if the key of the dictionary is a compile-time *constant* like for example the `int` `1` or the `string` "abc".

It's not possible if the key is a `Geschäftsjahr`. Then you would better bind to a property that performs the lookup for you, e.g.:

```
public string Text => ViewModelProperty[new Geschäftsjahr(2017, 2018)];
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

Comment: Is it possible, that I can bind multiple textboxes without the need for multiple properties in the ViewModel?

Comment: No, you will have to create a property for each value that you want to be able to display using this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of overriding the ToString() method of the class, create a new property that returns the formatted dates. Please see below.

New property that returns the correct formatted dates :

```
public string DatesDisplayText => "(Do your formatting here)";
```

Then your xaml can look like this :

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=ViewModelProperty[Key].DatesDisplayText} ... />
```

Comment: But then I am just getting and displaying the string-value of the key, right? I want to access the object behind the key in the dictionary. But with the solution I showed above, I am not able to access this object. And so I am not able to access properties on this object. Or do I have a mistake in my thoughts?